# Design an algorithm to solve this LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

$max \sum _{j=1}^nc_jx_j$

$\sum _{j=1}^na_jx_j\le b$  where $a_j,b$ are real numbers (not vectors)

$x_j\ge 0$ for all $j$

How to  design an algorihm to solve this LP?

Attempt: I have tried to solve it for different cases for the first constraint.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to reinvent the wheel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: so, it does not matter if $a_j,b$ are real numbers (not vectors).ok

Comment: If there is the one constraint, you could probably formulate the solution using the techniques for a knapsack problem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)